# WPF: When clicking a button embedded in a DataGrid, I want to fire SelectionChanged and then Click, but not at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, race-condition

I have a DataGrid with a list of Staff. When the user changes the selected row, I want the code-behind to perform an expensive "load" operation which pulls data from the database, and blocks further user input on the control until this is complete. This currently works fine. Each row also has a button, and when pushed, I want:

1. For the row of the button pressed to be selected
2. For the data to be loaded
3. For a function "Print" to fire, but not until the data loading function returns.

This is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewPrintProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:listViewPrintProblem="clr-namespace:ListViewPrintProblem"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance listViewPrintProblem:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContextChanged="MainWindow_OnDataContextChanged_OnDataContextChanged">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid
            x:Name="StaffList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding StaffItems}"
            GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStaffItem}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Name="printButton">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.PrintCommand}"  
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=printButton, Path=Content}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                        Command="{Binding SelectedStaffChangedCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=StaffList}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What happens right now is that when the user clicks on a button, this simultaneously triggers the "SelectedStaffChanged" function AND the "Print" function. While I'd be fine with both of these being triggered, it's a problem that they are simultaneous. "SelectedStaffChanged" is responsible for loading the new staff data. Sometimes the "Print" function finishes before the loading is finished, and then it prints data from the previously selected Staff instead of the new one.

Possible solutions that I can see are either:

1. Find a way to make sure that when the button is clicked, SelectedStaffChanged and Print are executed synchronously
2. Don't let SelectedStaffChanged fire from clicking on the button, and handle the loading and selected item changing in the code behind Print (but we do still want SelectedStaffChanged to fire when changing the selected row)
3. Add a IsLoading property to the code behind, and make Print wait until this is false before doing anything else. I've tried this one, and it works, but it's ugly and dangerous.

Edit - This is the code behind SelectedStaffChanged:

```
public string LoadedStaff { get; set; }
private void SelectedStaffChanged(Staff newStaff)
{
    if (LoadedStaff == newStaff?.Name) return;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(Load).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

}

private async void Load()
{
    Loading = true;

    LoadedStaff = await GetNameAsync(SelectedStaffItem);

    Loading = false;
}

private static async Task<string> GetNameAsync(Staff selectedStaffItem)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    switch (selectedStaffItem?.Name)
    {
        case "Moe":
            return "Moe Howard";
        case "Larry":
            return "Larry Fine";
        case "Curly":
            return "Curly Howard";
        default:
            return "Unknown";
    }

}
```

And this is the code behind Print:

```
private void MainWindow_OnPrint()
{
    var vm = DataContext as MainViewModel;
    MessageBox.Show(vm?.LoadedStaff);
}
```

When the user clicks on a row, the Load runs asynchrous and doesn't block user input, which is good. But when the user clicks on a print icon, the loading runs asynchrous and doesn't block the print, which is bad. So the print shows the name of the previously selected staff instead of the current one. If I remove the Task.Delay from load, it works correctly every time.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How do I make solution #1 or #2 happen? Preferably #1.

Comment: Post your current implementation of the command that is invoked when the Button is clicked then.

Comment: Ok, it's posted, with a bit more detail on what's going wrong.